# Equivalent of 'WHERE columnname IN' SQL syntax in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this scenario

```
public class TimeSheet
{
    [Key]
    public int TimeSheetID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class Approval
{
    [Key]
    public int ApprovalID { get; set; }
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(450)]
    public string Approver { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApprovalDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class ApprovalDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int ApprovalDetailID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(450)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

I want to the following syntax in EF.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   TimeSheet
WHERE
   UserName IN (SELECT
                   [AD].Username
                FROM
                   Approval [A]
                INNER JOIN 
                   ApprovalDetail [AD] ON [A].ApprovalID = [AD].ApprovalID
                WHERE
                   [A].Approver = 'warheat1990')
```

How to achieve this?

UPDATE :

My Repo

```
public IEnumerable<TimeSheet> List()
{
    return _timeSheet.AsEnumerable().ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<TimeSheet> ListByUsername(string username)
{
    return _timeSheet.Where(w => w.Username == username).ToList();
}
```

Comment: in linq we can do like -->  x.UserName.Contains(), maybe entity framework have that too

Comment: What is your DBContext in EF called? Can you also post your code where you want to do this, I assume your `Approval` class is already populated etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var usernamesByApprover = approvals
    .Where(a => a.Approver == "warheat1990")
    .SelectMany(a => a.Details.Select(d => d.Username));
var timesheetsByApprover = timesheets
    .Where(t => usernamesByApprover.Contains(t.Username));
```

Note that even if the query is split into two expressions, Entity Framework will convert it into a single SQL query once you evaluate the `timesheetsByApprover` variable because of [*deferred execution*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx).